# Speed up AAD B2C authentication flow

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have Azure Active Directory B2C sign in/sign up flows with custom policies.
This flows tae too long for end users:
signup ~ 10sec
signin ~ 7sec

I have decomposed signin time into queries:

```
https://[tenant].b2clogin.com/[tenant].onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_signup_signin/SelfAsserted.. - 1.5 sec
https://[tenant].b2clogin.com/[tenant].onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_signup_signin/api/CombinedSigninAndSignup/confirmed..  1.8 - 4 sec
https://[mydomain].com/api/next/auth/callback - 0.4 sec.
```

And we lose plus 2 seconds somewhere.

There is no external api calls in the UserJourney for sign in process.

Any idea how to optimise timing? What can be wrong with Azure configuration or policies?

Comment: Not sure if you can speedup Azure AD B2C. But I would recommend looking for something else, Azure AD B2C had never received the attention it should have...

Comment: Are the users in the same geographic area as the B2C tenant?

Comment: yes @rbrayb, I added the solution as the answer to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the geography. Users located in the same region with the b2c tenant have much better speed. The solution is to use Regional tenant orchestration.
Here is the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/b2c-global-identity-solutions